# Center the Mouse cursor inside the circle

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm Having trouble to center the default mouse cursor inside  a circle that follows the mouse cursor

[here is codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/dushyant1295/pen/dyvgmWz)

see this image

[image]

//  Create an html element and append to body

```
const dpkCursor = document.createElement("div");
dpkCursor.classList.add("dpkCursor");
document.body.appendChild(dpkCursor);
```

// Fuction that create circle to follow the cursor

```
function initCursor(speedOption = 0.25) {
  
    let dpkCursorMouse = { x: -100, y: -100 };
    let dpkCursorPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let speed = speedOption;
   

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      dpkCursorMouse.x = e.x;
      dpkCursorMouse.y = e.y;
    });

    const updatePosition = () => {
      dpkCursorPos.x += (dpkCursorMouse.x - dpkCursorPos.x) * speed;
      dpkCursorPos.y += (dpkCursorMouse.y - dpkCursorPos.y) * speed;
      
               
      dpkCursor.style.transform = `translate(${dpkCursorPos.x}px ,${dpkCursorPos.y}px)`;
    
    };

    function loop() {
      updatePosition();
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  
}
```

initCursor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `50%` from each side using

```
dpkCursor.style.transform = `translate(calc(${dpkCursorPos.x}px - 50%) ,calc(${dpkCursorPos.y}px - 50%))`;
```

```js
const dpkCursor = document.createElement("div");
dpkCursor.classList.add("dpkCursor");
document.body.appendChild(dpkCursor);


function initCursor(speedOption = 0.25) {
  
    let dpkCursorMouse = { x: -100, y: -100 };
    let dpkCursorPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let speed = speedOption;
   
    //center the circle around cursor       
 
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      dpkCursorMouse.x = e.x;
      dpkCursorMouse.y = e.y;
    });

    const updatePosition = () => {
      dpkCursorPos.x += (dpkCursorMouse.x - dpkCursorPos.x) * speed;
      dpkCursorPos.y += (dpkCursorMouse.y - dpkCursorPos.y) * speed;

      dpkCursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${dpkCursorPos.x}px - 50%) ,calc(${dpkCursorPos.y}px - 50%),0)`;
    
    };

    function loop() {
      updatePosition();
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  
}


initCursor()
```

```css
body{
  background:black;
}

.dpkCursor {
  height: 1.75rem;
  width: 1.75rem;
  position: fixed;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is the performant way to do so as you are using css calc() fn

Comment: @Dpk I don't know what you mean by *performant way* but this solution is dynamic and scalable. You don't have to change any variable if you decide to use a different circle with a different dimension

Comment: Yes you are right  But you remove translate3d  which is used as because it utilizes the GPU and gives the performance boost also  calc()  is cost too much  the main concern is performance

Comment: @Dpk you can keep it, simply put my code inside translate3D instead of translate

Comment: @Dpk I have update my code with the 3d and nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

I changed these lines -

```
const offset = 15;
dpkCursorPos.x += (dpkCursorMouse.x - dpkCursorPos.x - offset) * speed;
dpkCursorPos.y += (dpkCursorMouse.y - dpkCursorPos.y - offset) * speed;
```

Working demo -

```js
const dpkCursor = document.createElement("div");
dpkCursor.classList.add("dpkCursor");
document.body.appendChild(dpkCursor);

function initCursor(speedOption = 0.25) {
  let dpkCursorMouse = { x: -100, y: -100 };
  let dpkCursorPos = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let speed = speedOption;

  //center the circle around cursor

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    dpkCursorMouse.x = e.x;
    dpkCursorMouse.y = e.y;
  });

  const updatePosition = () => {
    const offset = 15;
    dpkCursorPos.x += (dpkCursorMouse.x - dpkCursorPos.x - offset) * speed;
    dpkCursorPos.y += (dpkCursorMouse.y - dpkCursorPos.y - offset) * speed;

    // dpkCursor.style.transform = `translate3d(${dpkCursorPos.x}px ,${dpkCursorPos.y}px, 0)`;

    dpkCursor.style.transform = `translate(${dpkCursorPos.x}px ,${dpkCursorPos.y}px)`;
  };

  function loop() {
    updatePosition();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

initCursor();
```

```css
body{
  background:black;
}

.dpkCursor {
  height: 1.75rem;
  width: 1.75rem;
  position: fixed;

  /* Hack For Verson 2 */
  /* margin:-14px; */
  
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works is it performant way to do so  as it you changed the line inside a function which is being called in requestAnimationFrame   and what if the circle grows the size in some case

Answer (score 0):

Can you just offset the shape with CSS? This worked for me:

```css
.dpkCursor {
  height: 1.75rem;
  width: 1.75rem;

  ...

  top: -0.875rem;
  left: -0.875rem;

  ...
}
```